# Camel with RabbitMQ exception only occurs on second message - mis-spelt exchange name

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq, spring-boot

I'm using Camel within a Spring boot application and integrate with RabbitMQ but am encountering strange behaviour.

My app has Restful endpointswhich convert the http request to a RabbitMQ message and publish this to a predefined exchange. There is a separate consumer app which listens to a queue and processes the messages.

I have deliberately entered an incorrect rabbitmq exchange name (invalidxchangename)to check that the application will fail if the exchange does not exist however the camel context starts without error and when I send in a **first** request is does not report any error. This message gets lost as there is no matching RabbitMQ exchange. When I submit a **second** request I receive the following exception which I would have expected on route startup.

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'invalidxchangename' in vhost
```

EDIT:
I've tried a more simple example to show the issue in Camel.

I've created a simple route as follows:

```
from("file:in?fileName=in.txt").log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "in here!").to("rabbitmq://localhost:5762/invalidexchange?declare=false");
```

where there is an existing RabbitMQ exchange called validexchange (so I have deliberately made a typo in the RabbitMQ uri). I would expect the camel route to fail at startup since the exchange doesn't exist, or even the first time it tries to process a new in.txt file.

What I am actually seeing in the logs is that on start up it reports no error and only on the 2nd invocation of the route does it report an error.

```
2015-03-11 16:17:04.356  INFO 9756 : ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-2 >>> (route2) from(file://in?fileName=in.txt) --> log[in here!] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:...
2015-03-11 16:17:04.360  INFO 9756 : ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-2 >>> (route2) log[in here!] --> rabbitmq://localhost:5762/customerchannel.exchang?declare=false <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:...
2015-03-11 16:17:45.073  INFO 9756 : ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-4 >>> (route2) from(file://in?fileName=in.txt) --> log[in here!] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers: ...
2015-03-11 16:17:45.079  INFO 9756 : ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-4 >>> (route2) log[in here!] --> rabbitmq://localhost:5762/customerchannel.exchang?declare=false <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:...
2015-03-11 16:17:45.092 ERROR 9756 : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-SBMELW7W-06220-59960-1426051020468-0-4). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'customerchannel.exchang' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first request is causing an error which closes the connection and logs the reason, and when you try to use the channel the second time it's returning an `AlreadyClosedException` with the message that caused the channel to close in the first call.

You can test this by trying to publish the second message to a different exchange name in the same channel and checking which exchange is in the error. E.g. publish the second message to `invalidxchangename2` and you should still see `invalidxchangename` as the exchange in the error.

To fix, you should handle the publish result when you publish and re-establish the connection if there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that a message got delivered to a RabbitMQ queue, then you have to use publisher confirms: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

That you are able to publish a message it doesn't mean that the message will reach a queue. You could go to a mailbox and leave a letter inside, but between the time you left the letter there and a postman picked up, many things could have happened, for example, the mailbox catching fire and so on.